# How to map SOPClass,Accession,MPPS,NumberOfInstances, ParticipantObjectContainsStudy into Fhir AuditEVent

Tags: hl7-fhir

As per this link https://www.hl7.org/FHIR/2015Sep/auditevent.html,
audit event is based on the IHE-ATNA Audit record definitions, originally from RFC 3881, and now managed by DICOM (see DICOM Part 15 Annex A5 ).

[DICOM Part 15 Annex A5](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/html/part15.html#sect_A.5) has few DICOM extension nodes as shown below:

SOPClass,Accession,MPPS,NumberOfInstances, ParticipantObjectContainsStudy.

Where can I map this information in Fhir AuditEvent?

Answer (score 0):

These parts of the DICOM 'Audit Trail Message' standard were not seen as fitting the 80% principle of FHIR.

In most of the case these can nicely be encoded as an identifier in the AuditEvent.object.identifier. This is the more general use.

You could define an extension.

Are you trying to create a general-purpose translation, or do you have these elements in practice? The experience of those participating in the efforts indicated that these are not used in practice, or would be better encoded simply as AuditEvent.object.identifier.

Comment: Thanks John for your quick response.As you have mentioned we can fit this information in AuditEvent.object.identifier, but not clear whether we need to have this information as part of FHIR AuditEvent. I would like to know what FHIR standarad says about these nodes. Are these mandatory elements. Also could you please provide me some examples for DataExport and DataImport Audit Events. Or any example   on AuditEvent.object.identifier usage.